# Are sleep stations on-campus effective in promoting productivity of students?

Tags: united-states, university, health

Several universities in the United States have begun setting up areas (usually in the library) for students to rest, ideally for those doing all-nighters. Its purpose is to help its students cope with the lack of sleep.  Not much has been said about its effectivity.

The student government of our university has been discussing employing the same concept  on-campus. I would like to know if this is a good idea or if it is more likely to promote a culture of lethargy.

Comment: My opinion would be that it would encourage unhealthy sleep practices such as all-nighters, and would be treating a symptom rather than the cause (procrastination, unhealthy course loads, bad prioritisation of students personal time, etc). Unless these are bunks for students to get a few hours of rest in, I think promoting sleep-hygiene would be better. But that's just my opinion

Comment: Is it only for students?  There's nothing bad about taking a nap.

Comment: My library in undergrad was used for that purpose unofficially anyway.

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately, I am not aware of any particularly significant study that analyzes the effectiveness or convenience of on-campus sleep stations.

There is, however, significant research on the effectiveness of "power naps" for restoring mental performance, especially in somewhat sleep-deprived individuals. E.g. [1],[2].

Personally, I think that it seems somewhat unlikely that it would encourage a culture of lethargy. In fact, I would be more concerned with the opposite; that it would promote a culture of sleep-deprived students (either due to bad time management or to being overworked) that rely on shortcuts to temporarily restore their mental capabilities while maintaining the relatively unhealthy habit of not sleeping properly at night.

[[1] Mednick, S. C., Nakayama, K., Cantero, J. L., Atienza, M., Levin, A. A., Pathak, N., & Stickgold, R. (2002). The restorative effect of naps on perceptual deterioration. Nature neuroscience, 5(7), 677-681.](https://doi.org/10.1038/nn864)

[[2] Naitoh, P., Englund, C. E., & Ryman, D. (1982). Restorative power of naps in designing continuous work schedules. Journal of human ergology, 11(Supplement), 259-278.](https://doi.org/10.11183/jhe1972.11.Supplement_259)